# object constructor using this into a runnable

Tags: android, runnable

I m trying to call an object constructor into a runnable but Eclipse return error.
The

```
simpleAdapter = new SimpleStandardAdapter(this, manager, LEVEL_NUMBER, this, headendDataLookup, findViewById(R.id.moduleDetailView));
```

is not accepted into the runnable. the problem are related to this variables. the eclipse suggest theses variable with Runnable

```
public void updateTreeView()
    {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (treeView == null)
                    return;
                updateTreeContent();
                simpleAdapter = new SimpleStandardAdapter(this, manager, LEVEL_NUMBER, this, headendDataLookup, findViewById(R.id.moduleDetailView));
                setTreeAdapter(TreeType.SIMPLE);
                setCollapsible(true);
                registerForContextMenu(treeView);
                manager.collapseChildren(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Two things:
What is SimpleStandardAdapter? I am not sure it's on any android lib, are you sure that is working fine?
But in any case, the "this" you pass as -I guess- a context or a view should be reffering to your activity.  Right now it is reffering to your Runnable object. (usually just solved by YourActivity.this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a context object. So use

```
  ActivityName.this
```

instead of `this`.

In your case `this` points to `runnable`

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
  simpleAdapter = new SimpleStandardAdapter(ActivityName.this , manager, LEVEL_NUMBER, ActivityName.this , headendDataLookup, findViewById(R.id.moduleDetailView));
```